# how to read csv into df in pyspark if column name has comma as column delimiters?

Tags: csv, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

my csv file has these columns:

```
'column1', 'column2,structured_well_data'  , 'column3', 'column4,distributed_sys_org23454'
```

etc.
my code that reads a csv file is this:

```
pandas_config =  df_config.toPandas()

for index, row in pandas_config.iterrows(): 
    
    row["sor_path"] = "/" + row["sor_path"]
   
    df_csv = spark.read.format("delta").load(row["sor_path"], format = "csv", header = "true", inferschema = "true")
    df_csv.createOrReplaceTempView("V_" + row["sor_name"])
    print("V_" + row["sor_name"] + " has been created..")
```

i m working on this:

```
df_csv = spark.read.format("delta").load(row["sor_path"], format = "csv", header = "true", inferschema = "true")
```

i tried adding option:

```
df_csv = spark.read.option('delimiter', ',').format("delta").load(row["sor_path"], format = "csv", header = "true", inferschema = "true")
```

but not working.

the csv file looks like this:

[image: kk]

How to deal with this case?

Comment: Not sure how this data source relates to the csv reader, but what happens when you pass `quote="'"`?

Comment: @ernest_k, mm i dont know , let me try

Comment: @ernest_k, sorry i dont know what quote means, is it a parameter?

Comment: Yes. One passed the same way as `header = "true"` is passed, or an option, `spark.read.option('quote', "'")....`

Comment: @ernest_k, ohh i m noob with spark, let me try this param

Comment: @ernest_k, i tried, quote param seems to be for smth else.. it still only shows the first 10 or so columns, the problem is csv file column names goes to 2nd row

Comment: Well, maybe it's a question of that "delate" data source (I've never used it). The normal csv reader works with `'column1','column2,structured_well_data','column3','column4,distributed_sys_org23454'
val1,val2,val3,val4` using `spark.read.csv(file, quote="'", header=True)`

Comment: @ernest_k, i added a screenshot of my csv file , i can read it in excel if i change the reading options for excel, but i m working in pyspark